# Struggling to write code and tests for my Tube System program, TDD using Rspec and Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am writing a small program for a train system.

I have a passenger, coach, train and station class (and thus, a spec test for each).

**My test for my passenger class is as such:**

```
let (:passenger) {Passenger.new}

  it "should not be touched in to a station when initialized" do
    expect(passenger.touchedin?).to be false
  end

  it "should be able to enter coach" do
    coach = Coach.new
    passenger.enter(coach)
    expect{coach.to receive(:enter)}
  end

  it "should be able to alight coach" do
    coach = Coach.new
    passenger.alight(coach)
    expect{coach.to receive(:alight)}
  end

  it "should be able to touch into station" do
    station = Station.new
    passenger.touchin(station)
    expect{station.to receive(:touchin)}
  end

  it "should be able to touch out of station" do
    station = Station.new
    passenger.touchout(station)
    expect{station.to receive(:touchout)}
  end
end
```

**And my passenger class is like this (at the moment :p):**

```
class Passenger

  def initialize
    @touchedin = false
  end

  def enter(coach)

  end

  def touchedin?
    @touchedin
  end

  def alight(coach)

  end

  def touchin(station)

  end

  def touchout(station)

  end
end
```

I am unsure how to satisfy my tests, if my tests are even correct in the first place.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not really said how you're modeling the relationship between coaches and passengers, but one way I could think of could be as follows.  I'm just putting enough for the coach/passenger relationship (so nothing about touching in as this involves the station) - and I'm using minitest syntax, but I think you can get the idea of what's happening.

```
class Coach
  def initialize
    @passengers = []
  end

  ...
end


class Passenger
  def initialize
    @touched_in = false
  end

  def alight(coach)
    coach.passengers << self.uid # or self, if you want the whole passenger object available
  end

  ...
end 


coach = Coach.new
assert_empty coach.passengers

joe = Passenger.new
refute_includes coach.passengers, joe.uid # or joe
joe.alight(coach)
assert_includes coach.passengers, joe.uid # or joe
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. Sorry that I didn't explain my model relationship, will learn from that :)

Comment: not at all :) if it helped please check the answer so it's out of the 'unanswered' queue!